# how to load csv file based on header data using sqlldr

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, sql-loader

I have a `.csv` file in which first line always contains `header` information. But the position of the header columns are not fixed. For example,

`file 1 has below mentioned data`

`Name,ID,Mailing Details`

`X,1,US`

`file 2 has below mentioned data`

`Mailing Details,Name,ID`

`UK,Y,10`

Here if we see the column names are interchanged due to which i cannot define static control file.
So can any one help me, like how can write my control file to search for the header column name and put that into the table.

`my table structure is`

`ID,Name,Mailing_Details`

Many Thanks.

Comment: how many such files .csv's are we looking at ?

Comment: 50+ files in a day

Comment: How many combinations of columns ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming for this 3 column & 6 combinations; an elsif ladder in shell script can used to frame the ask here

Hoping this would be helpful in arriving at your desired ask

```
for file in 1.txt

do

f1=`head "${file}" -n1 | tr A-Z a-z | sed 's/,//g'`


if [ $f1 == "idnamemailing_details" ] 
then
        echo "logic 1 -> ${file}"
        echo "
        load data 
        infile '${file}' 
        badfile 'badfile1.csv'
        discardfile 'discard1.csv' 
        append
        into table schema.table
        fields terminated by ',' 
        ( id, name, mailing_details ) " > loader.ctl
        sleep 1
        sqlldr user/pwd@schema  control=loader.ctl 
        break

elif [ $f1 == "idmailing_detailsname" ] 
then
        echo "logic 2 -> ${file}"
        echo "
        load data 
        infile '${file}' 
        badfile 'badfile1.csv'
        discardfile 'discard1.csv' 
        append
        into table schema.table
        fields terminated by ',' 
        ( id, mailing_details,name ) " > loader.ctl
        sleep 1
        sqlldr user/pwd@schema  control=loader.ctl 
        break

elif [ $f1 == "namemailing_detailsid" ] 
then
        echo "logic 3 -> ${file}"
        echo "
        load data 
        infile '${file}' 
        badfile 'badfile1.csv'
        discardfile 'discard1.csv' 
        append
        into table schema.table
        fields terminated by ',' 
        ( name, mailing_details ,id) " > loader.ctl
        sleep 1
        sqlldr user/pwd@schema  control=loader.ctl 
        break

elif [ $f1 == "nameidmailing_details" ] 
        then
        echo "logic 4 -> ${file}"
        echo "
        load data 
        infile '${file}' 
        badfile 'badfile1.csv'
        discardfile 'discard1.csv' 
        append
        into table schema.table
        fields terminated by ',' 
        ( name, id, mailing_details ) " > loader.ctl
        sleep 1
        sqlldr user/pwd@schema  control=loader.ctl 
        break

elif [ $f1 == "mailing_detailsidname" ] 
then
        echo "logic 5 -> ${file}"
        echo "
        load data 
        infile '${file}' 
        badfile 'badfile1.csv'
        discardfile 'discard1.csv' 
        append
        into table schema.table
        fields terminated by ',' 
        ( mailing_details,id,name ) " > loader.ctl
        sleep 1
        sqlldr user/pwd@schema  control=loader.ctl 
        break

elif [ $f1 == "mailing_detailsnameid" ] 
then
        echo "logic 6 -> ${file}"
        echo "
        load data 
        infile '${file}' 
        badfile 'badfile1.csv'
        discardfile 'discard1.csv' 
        append
        into table schema.table
        fields terminated by ',' 
        ( mailing_details, name,id  ) " > loader.ctl
        sleep 1
        sqlldr user/pwd@schema  control=loader.ctl 
        break

fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLLDR can't do this on its own...

I think you have a few options:

1. If there are too many format combinations; using a script, process the first line and dynamically build a control file.
2. If you have a limited number of formats; using a script, look at the first line and match the format to the control file.
3. Look for another solution... Ditch the SQLLDR and use external tables perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

You can try with `BOUNDFILLER or FILLER` as below.

> BOUNDFILLER or FILLER is a data file mapped field that does not
>   correspond to a database column. Filler fields are assigned values
>   from the data fields to which they are mapped

.

```
   load data
  infile 'file1.csv'           
  infile 'file2.csv'
    append
    into table SCHEMA.TABLE
    fields terminated by ';' optionally enclosed by '"'
    trailing nullcols
    (
      source_field1     BOUNDFILLER,
      source_field2     BOUNDFILLER,
      source_field3     BOUNDFILLER,
      destination_field1 ":source_field1",
      destination_field2 ":source_field2",
      destination_field3 ":source_field3");
```

More details can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-EAB9BE96-6F29-4623-9BEF-323C2FE05CB7.htm#SUTIL1149)

Comment: BOUNDFILLER is also working similar to the static control file format, where i had to explicitly mention the column names. so as per my requirement if i change the column sequence, then it is not working.